# Running Ruby on Rails + Phusion passenger with Nginx+mysql in 32 bit or 64 bit Linux OS server and its performance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, 32bit-64bit

I have a Java background, and am new to Ruby on Rails, and have a lot of confusion choosing 32-bit or 64-bit Linux OS for my server.

This is what I know, please correct me if I am wrong:

A 32-bit OS cannot utilize more than 4GB of RAM, but through [pae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) it's possible. In this way, the extra memory is useful even though no single regular application can access it all simultaneously. So I plan to go with a 64-bit Linux OS server.

1. Is there a 64-bit [Ruby enterprise edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) available?
2. Is it better to install 32-bit MySQL 5 or 64-bit MySQL 5 in 64-bit Linux OS? I will have 32GB RAM.
3. Does running a 32-bit application on 64-bit OS, and considering MySQL 32-bit on a 64-bit OS, have any physical memory (RAM) restrictions? I would like to know any pitfalls or cons of running a 32-bit MySQL on a 64-bit OS.
4. Assuming I installed 32-bit MySQL 5 on a 64-bit Linux OS, is it capable of utilizing my RAM efficiently? I am asking this because 32-bit application processes cannot use more than 4GB RAM per process. (Correct me if I am wrong) 32-bit Mysql will run as a single processes (mysqld) for N number of databases. If I have 100 databases, for transactions to 100 DBs, MySQL uses 4GB of RAM due to MySQL's 32-bit limit.
5. Assuming I installed 64-bit MySQL 5 on a 64-bit Linux OS, are there any gem incompatibilities between MySQL 64-bit and Ruby on Rails? I would like to know if there is a MySQL 5 64-bit gem available? Note: I am using MySQL adapter not MySQL 2.
6. I plan to use Phusion Passenger for my Rails application deployment. I have 100 Rails applications and my questions are:

   1. Is there a 64-bit Phusion Passenger available. If yes, where can I find it?
   2. If I am running 100 Rails applications with 32-bit Phusion Passenger in 64-bit OS, will my Phusion utilize my 32-GB RAM efficiently?
   3. Are 100 Rails applications in Phusion Passenger i100 processes or 100 threads?
7. To utilize my hardware efficiently through Ruby on Rails + Nginx-Phusion Passenger + MySQL, what should I need to do regarding 32-bit and 64-bit applications as well as OS?

My application information is:

```
Ruby - 1.8.7
Rails - 2.3.5
Database - mysql5
Database adapter - MySQL, Note - not mysql2 
server - Phussion Passenger + Nginx Module
```

My dedicated server configuration is:

```
OS         Debian 32-bit or 64-bit (still not decided)

CPU         AMD Opteron™ 3280
Quantity    Octo-Core
Clock Rate  8x 2.4 GHz (so total 19.2 GHz)
Processor passmark score is 5722 [http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Opteron+3280]


Main Memory

Capacity    32 GB RAM
Type    DIMM (DDR3)

Hard Disks

Quantity    2
Capacity    2,000 GB (ie) 2 TB + 2 TB
Type    SATA II, 7,200 rpm, 8 MB
RAID    RAID 1 by software

Mainboard

Chipset AMD 880G
Network Broadcom BCM57780
```

Any reviews and comments about server configuration and 32-bit/64-bit application/OS architecture are always welcome and I am glad to take it.

Comment: Marked for transfer over to ServerFault. Somebody should be able to better help you over there.

Comment: If you have 32GB of RAM, use a 64-bit OS!

Comment: If you have <= 4GB of RAM, use a 32-bit OS and ruby you'll save a lot of RAM (it might be tricky to get PAE working or to get 32-bit ruby to run in a 64-bit environment, but theoretically possible if you want the RAM savings, just much harder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a 64-bit [Ruby enterprise edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) available?

1. Ruby is free, and there is no enterprise edition or other edition.

> Is it better to install 32-bit MySQL 5 or 64-bit MySQL 5 in 64-bit Linux OS? I will have 32GB RAM.

2. Use 64bit.

> Does running a 32-bit application on 64-bit OS, and considering MySQL 32-bit on a 64-bit OS, have any physical memory (RAM) restrictions? I would like to know any pitfalls or cons of running a 32-bit MySQL on a 64-bit OS.

3. There is also a 64-bit version of MySQL available so there is no problem.

> Assuming I installed 32-bit MySQL 5 on a 64-bit Linux OS, is it capable of utilizing my RAM efficiently? I am asking this because 32-bit application processes cannot use more than 4GB RAM per process. (Correct me if I am wrong) 32-bit Mysql will run as a single processes (mysqld) for N number of databases. If I have 100 databases, for transactions to 100 DBs, MySQL uses 4GB of RAM due to MySQL's 32-bit limit.

4. Use the 64-bit version and you don't even have to think about this.

> Assuming I installed 64-bit MySQL 5 on a 64-bit Linux OS, are there any gem incompatibilities between MySQL 64-bit and Ruby on Rails? I would like to know if there is a MySQL 5 64-bit gem available? Note: I am using MySQL adapter not MySQL 2.

5. It's not important which version of MySQL you use because the interface is the Unix socket or the TCP/IP socket which doesn't depend on 32 or 64 bit.

> I plan to use Phusion Passenger for my Rails application deployment. I have 100 >Rails applications and my questions are:
>
> 1. Is there a 64-bit Phusion Passenger available. If yes, where can I find it?
> 2. If I am running 100 Rails applications with 32-bit Phusion Passenger in 64 bit OS, will my Phusion utilize my 32-GB RAM efficiently?
> 3. Are 100 Rails applications in Phusion Passenger i100 processes or 100 threads?

6. I dont know exactly, but you should also think about using Thin and nginx which is as good an equivalent to Phusion Passenger when it comes to performance.

> To utilize my hardware efficiently through Ruby on Rails + Nginx-Phusion Passenger + MySQL, what should I need to do regarding 32-bit and 64-bit applications as well as OS?

7. Use 64-bit!

Also I would suggest you to buy a RAID card.

Comment: There is such a thing as ruby enterprise edition - basically ruby 1.8.7 with a better garbage collector and some other patches. No longer under development though.

Comment: Thats not what I understand as "enterprise" because there is no kind of support and you also dont pay anything for it,...

Comment: It may not be the traditional meaning of enterprise but it is what its developers (phusion) call it